# How to compile C++ codes in Linux with source files hidden?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, gcc, compilation

Is there anyway to compile C++ source files in Linux and make these files unreadable to users? Either have the files encrypted or read them into memory is acceptable.
We are developing a Linux based software and we don't want our users to have direct access to our source code files.

Comment: I think your best bet is to produce binaries for the popular linux distributions.

Comment: if the files are encrypted, you need to provide the decryption key for the compiler to be able to read the source.

Comment: Trying to make bits not copyable is like trying to make water not wet.

Comment: Take care with how you use material that is under the GPL or you'll be required to release the source code to the public. That's a license issue, not a code issue, though. Not sure if it's on topic here, and even if it is it's a topic better discussed with lawyers..

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: That's actually not so hard. Either heat it to 373K or chill it to about 223K. As a physicist I may also have an opinion on uncopyable bits, but those need to be chilled quite a bit further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a binary is created from C++ source files, the original source files are not needed in order to run the program. You can distribute only the compiled program.

Answer (score -1):

Just build a container image with your software and its dependencies and run it anywhere. No need to distribute sources or compile for specific distributions.

You can use [Flatpak](https://flatpak.org/) or Docker, for example.